# My wordpress website (Theme-Casamia-olderversion) My main navigation isn't active on hover and will not display the dropdown sub menus

Tags: css

This is the CSS for the header.main navigation menu. . .again will NOT display the dropdown menu on hover at all, not activity on hover whatsoever. . .please help. . .I'm not entirely proficient with the rules, I've been knowing enough to get by, but when problems such as this arise, the issue seems to escape my depth as to this point. . .so I'm needing to reach out. IF ANYONE can please examine and help me I would be EXTREMELY GRATEFUL to say the least. Anyone?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title> My Blog</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/themes/casamia/7league/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="pingback" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/xmlrpc.php" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Blog &raquo; Feed" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Blog &raquo; Comments Feed" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/comments/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Blog &raquo; Fullwidth Slider Comments Feed" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/fullwidth-slider/feed/" />
<script type="text/javascript">
window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/14.0.0\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/14.0.0\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"https:\/\/besthomes4sale.info\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=6.0.2"}};
/*! This file is auto-generated */
!function(e,a,t){var n,r,o,i=a.createElement("canvas"),p=i.getContext&&i.getContext("2d");function s(e,t){var a=String.fromCharCode,e=(p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,e),0,0),i.toDataURL());return p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,t),0,0),e===i.toDataURL()}function c(e){var t=a.createElement("script");t.src=e,t.defer=t.type="text/javascript",a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t)}for(o=Array("flag","emoji"),t.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},r=0;r<o.length;r++)t.supports[o[r]]=function(e){if(!p||!p.fillText)return!1;switch(p.textBaseline="top",p.font="600 32px Arial",e){case"flag":return s([127987,65039,8205,9895,65039],[127987,65039,8203,9895,65039])?!1:!s([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819])&&!s([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]);case"emoji":return!s([129777,127995,8205,129778,127999],[129777,127995,8203,129778,127999])}return!1}(o[r]),t.supports.everything=t.supports.everything&&t.supports[o[r]],"flag"!==o[r]&&(t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&t.supports[o[r]]);t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!t.supports.flag,t.DOMReady=!1,t.readyCallback=function(){t.DOMReady=!0},t.supports.everything||(n=function(){t.readyCallback()},a.addEventListener?(a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n,!1),e.addEventListener("load",n,!1)):(e.attachEvent("onload",n),a.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===a.readyState&&t.readyCallback()})),(e=t.source||{}).concatemoji?c(e.concatemoji):e.wpemoji&&e.twemoji&&(c(e.twemoji),c(e.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 0.07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-css-css'  href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/themes/casamia/style.css?ver=6.0.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css'  href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/themes/casamia/font-awesome.css?ver=6.0.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='custom-css-css'  href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/themes/casamia/7league/css/customcss.php?ver=6.0.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=6.0.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=6.0.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=6.0.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='global-styles-inline-css' type='text/css'>
body{--wp--preset--color--black: #0066ed;--wp--preset--color--cyan-bluish-gray: #abb8c3;--wp--preset--color--white: #ffffff;--wp--preset--color--pale-pink: #f78da7;--wp--preset--color--vivid-red: #cf2e2e;--wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-orange: #ff6900;--wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-amber: #fcb900;--wp--preset--color--light-green-cyan: #7bdcb5;/* --wp--preset--color--vivid-green-cyan: #00d084; *//* --wp--preset--color--pale-cyan-blue: #8ed1fc; *//* --wp--preset--color--vivid-cyan-blue: #0693e3; *//* --wp--preset--color--vivid-purple: #9b51e0; *//* --wp--preset--gradient--vivid-cyan-blue-to-vivid-purple:linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(6,147,227,1) 0%,rgb(155,81,224) 100%); */--wp--preset--gradient--light-green-cyan-to-vivid-green-cyan:linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(122,220,180) 0%,rgb(0,208,130) 100%);--wp--preset--gradient--luminous-vivid-amber-to-luminous-vivid-orange:linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(252,185,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,105,0,1) 100%);--wp--preset--gradient--luminous-vivid-orange-to-vivid-red:linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(255,105,0,1) 0%,rgb(207,46,46) 100%);--wp--preset--gradient--very-light-gray-to-cyan-bluish-gray:linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(238,238,238) 0%,rgb(169,184,195) 100%);--wp--preset--gradient--cool-to-warm-spectrum:linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(74,234,220) 0%,rgb(151,120,209) 20%,rgb(207,42,186) 40%,rgb(238,44,130) 60%,rgb(251,105,98) 80%,rgb(254,248,76) 100%);--wp--preset--gradient--blush-light-purple:linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(255,206,236) 0%,rgb(152,150,240) 100%);--wp--preset--gradient--blush-bordeaux:linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(254,205,165) 0%,rgb(254,45,45) 50%,rgb(107,0,62) 100%);--wp--preset--gradient--luminous-dusk:linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(255,203,112) 0%,rgb(199,81,192) 50%,rgb(65,88,208) 100%);--wp--preset--gradient--pale-ocean:linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(255,245,203) 0%,rgb(182,227,212) 50%,rgb(51,167,181) 100%);--wp--preset--gradient--electric-grass:linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(202,248,128) 0%,rgb(113,206,126) 100%);--wp--preset--gradient--midnight:linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(2,3,129) 0%,rgb(40,116,252) 100%);--wp--preset--duotone--dark-grayscale:url('#wp-duotone-dark-grayscale');--wp--preset--duotone--grayscale:url('#wp-duotone-grayscale');--wp--preset--duotone--purple-yellow:url('#wp-duotone-purple-yellow');--wp--preset--duotone--blue-red:url('#wp-duotone-blue-red');--wp--preset--duotone--midnight:url('#wp-duotone-midnight');--wp--preset--duotone--magenta-yellow:url('#wp-duotone-magenta-yellow');--wp--preset--duotone--purple-green:url('#wp-duotone-purple-green');--wp--preset--duotone--blue-orange:url('#wp-duotone-blue-orange');--wp--preset--font-size--small: 13px;--wp--preset--font-size--medium: 20px;--wp--preset--font-size--large: 36px;--wp--preset--font-size--x-large: 42px;}.has-black-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--black) !important;}.has-cyan-bluish-gray-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--cyan-bluish-gray) !important;}.has-white-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--white) !important;}.has-pale-pink-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--pale-pink) !important;}.has-vivid-red-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-red) !important;}.has-luminous-vivid-orange-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-orange) !important;}.has-luminous-vivid-amber-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-amber) !important;}.has-light-green-cyan-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--light-green-cyan) !important;}.has-vivid-green-cyan-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-green-cyan) !important;}.has-pale-cyan-blue-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--pale-cyan-blue) !important;}.has-vivid-cyan-blue-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-cyan-blue) !important;}.has-vivid-purple-color{color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-purple) !important;}.has-black-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--black) !important;}.has-cyan-bluish-gray-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--cyan-bluish-gray) !important;}.has-white-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--white) !important;}.has-pale-pink-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--pale-pink) !important;}.has-vivid-red-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-red) !important;}.has-luminous-vivid-orange-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-orange) !important;}.has-luminous-vivid-amber-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-amber) !important;}.has-light-green-cyan-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--light-green-cyan) !important;}.has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-green-cyan) !important;}.has-pale-cyan-blue-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--pale-cyan-blue) !important;}.has-vivid-cyan-blue-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-cyan-blue) !important;}.has-vivid-purple-background-color{background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-purple) !important;}.has-black-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--black) !important;}.has-cyan-bluish-gray-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--cyan-bluish-gray) !important;}.has-white-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--white) !important;}.has-pale-pink-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--pale-pink) !important;}.has-vivid-red-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-red) !important;}.has-luminous-vivid-orange-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-orange) !important;}.has-luminous-vivid-amber-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--luminous-vivid-amber) !important;}.has-light-green-cyan-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--light-green-cyan) !important;}.has-vivid-green-cyan-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-green-cyan) !important;}.has-pale-cyan-blue-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--pale-cyan-blue) !important;}.has-vivid-cyan-blue-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-cyan-blue) !important;}.has-vivid-purple-border-color{border-color: var(--wp--preset--color--vivid-purple) !important;}.has-vivid-cyan-blue-to-vivid-purple-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--vivid-cyan-blue-to-vivid-purple) !important;}.has-light-green-cyan-to-vivid-green-cyan-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--light-green-cyan-to-vivid-green-cyan) !important;}.has-luminous-vivid-amber-to-luminous-vivid-orange-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--luminous-vivid-amber-to-luminous-vivid-orange) !important;}.has-luminous-vivid-orange-to-vivid-red-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--luminous-vivid-orange-to-vivid-red) !important;}.has-very-light-gray-to-cyan-bluish-gray-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--very-light-gray-to-cyan-bluish-gray) !important;}.has-cool-to-warm-spectrum-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--cool-to-warm-spectrum) !important;}.has-blush-light-purple-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--blush-light-purple) !important;}.has-blush-bordeaux-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--blush-bordeaux) !important;}.has-luminous-dusk-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--luminous-dusk) !important;}.has-pale-ocean-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--pale-ocean) !important;}.has-electric-grass-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--electric-grass) !important;}.has-midnight-gradient-background{background: var(--wp--preset--gradient--midnight) !important;}.has-small-font-size{font-size: var(--wp--preset--font-size--small) !important;}.has-medium-font-size{font-size: var(--wp--preset--font-size--medium) !important;}.has-large-font-size{font-size: var(--wp--preset--font-size--large) !important;}.has-x-large-font-size{font-size: var(--wp--preset--font-size--x-large) !important;}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0' id='jquery-core-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2' id='jquery-migrate-js'></script>
<link rel="https://api.w.org/" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-json/" /><link rel="alternate" type="application/json" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/1952" /><link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 6.0.2" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/" />
<link rel='shortlink' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbesthomes4sale.info%2F" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbesthomes4sale.info%2F&#038;format=xml" />
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:regular|Ruda:regular|' />
<style type='text/css'>#cbackground {background-color:}</style><link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="New Objects Feed" href="http://localhost/immo/?feed=rss2&amp;post_type=estate"><style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
    </header .main-color: #0066ed;
<div id="container">
            <section id="overheader">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="fleft">
                    <i class='sc_fa_icon icon-phone' ></i><a href="tel: 232-122-5932">Call us now: (232) 122-5932</a></div>
                <div class="fright text-right">
                                    </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div> 
        </section>
         
    <section id="page" class="page">
        <header id="headline"> 
            <div id="headmenu">
                <div id="nav_gradient">
                    <div id="navline_wrap">
                        <div id="nav" class="page">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div id="brand">
                                    <a href="https://besthomes4sale.info">
                                        <img src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/themes/casamia/7league/default/logo.png' alt='' />                                 </a>
                                </div>    
                                <div id="navleft">
                                    <nav class="menu-main-container"><ul id="menu" class="main-menu main-menu-1 sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow"><li id="menu-item-4088" class="c1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-1952 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children has-submenu"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/" data-v="go Back">Home<span>go Back</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><i class='icon-arrow-up'></i><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/home-search/">Home Search</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/home-recent-objects/">Home Recent Objects</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/home-featured-objects/">Home Featured Objects</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/home-map/">Home Map</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4091" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/fullwidth-slider/imageheader/">Page with Imageheader</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4089" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/fullwidth-slider/home-mapslider/">Mapslider</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-1952 current_page_item"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/">Fullwidth Slider</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/home-boxed-slider/">Home boxed Slider</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4090" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/fullwidth-slider/home-with-headlines/">Home with Headline</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/fullwidth-slider/elasticslider/">Smooth slider</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4070" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-submenu"><a href="#">Listings</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/homes-grid/">Listing grid</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/homes-list/">Listing list</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4071" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-submenu"><a href="#">Browse by&#8230;</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4072" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-estatecity"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estatecity/new-york/">City: New York</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4073" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-estatekind"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estatekind/house/">Kind: House</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4074" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-estatefeature"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estatefeature/pool/">Feature: Pool</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4075" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-estatetype"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estatetype/sale/">Type: Sale</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4069" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-submenu"><a href="#">Shortcodes</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/elements/">Typographie</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/columns/">Columns &#038; Sections</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4095" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/flickr/">Flickr</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4096" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/videos/">Videos</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4098" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/testimonial-shortcodes/">Testimonial Shortcodes</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4097" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/google-maps/">Google Maps</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/3096-2/">Skills</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4077" class="c1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children has-submenu"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/" data-v="Stunning!">Features<span>Stunning!</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/sidebar-right/">Sidebar right</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4080" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/sidebar-left/">Sidebar left</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/full-width/">Full width</a></li>
header .main-menu > ul li:hover > ulla
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    <li id="menu-item-4103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/portfolio/sortable-3-col/">Portfolio Sortable</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/portfolio/quickgallery-3-col/">Quickgallery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-3950" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/blog/" data-v="Our Blog">News<span>Our Blog</span></a></li>
</ul></nav>                             </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>                       
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header> 
        <!-- elastic slider --> 
<div id="smoothslider_container" class="nocsl  ">
    <div id="smoothslider" >
        <section id="smooth_header" class="header custom_header smoothslider"> 
                <a class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/blog-1.jpg'><img src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/blog-1.jpg' alt='' /></a><a class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0010.jpg'><img src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0010.jpg' alt='' /></a><a class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0006.jpg'><img src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0006.jpg' alt='' /></a><a class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0009.jpg'><img src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0009.jpg' alt='' /></a><a class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0007.jpg'><img src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0007.jpg' alt='' /></a><a class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0008.jpg'><img src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0008.jpg' alt='' /></a><a class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/blog-4.jpg'><img src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/blog-4.jpg' alt='' /></a> 
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) 
        {
   
    color: #0066ed;
    text-decoration: none;
            autoScrollingInterval: 10,
            autoScrollingStep: 1,
            scrollToAnimationDuration: 1000,
            autoScrollingDirection: "backAndForth",
            });
                    }); 
        </script>
 
        <div class="mainsection">
            <div class="inner"> 
            
<!-- Page  -->  
    <div id="page-sidebar-no-sidebar">
        <div id="content" class="equal_height">  
            <div class='sc_column one_fourth ' >
<h4><i class='sc_fa_icon icon-compass'  style='font-size: 22px; ' ></i> &nbsp;Responsive</h4>
<p>Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore sed diam nonumy.</p>
</div>
<div class='sc_column one_fourth ' >
<h4><i class='sc_fa_icon icon-font'  style='font-size: 22px; ' ></i> &nbsp;600+ Webfonts</h4>
<p>Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore sed diam nonumy.</p>
</div>
<div class='sc_column one_fourth ' >
<h4><i class='sc_fa_icon icon-th-large'  style='font-size: 22px; ' ></i> &nbsp;SEO ready</h4>
<p>Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore sed diam nonumy.</p>
</div>
<div class='sc_column one_fourth last ' >
<h4><i class='sc_fa_icon icon-plus'  style='font-size: 22px; ' ></i> &nbsp;Multipurpose</h4>
<p>Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore sed diam nonumy.</p>
</div><div class='clear'></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p class="tagline">Our Featured Properties<span>Some really interesting properties for you</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
[estate_teaser id=&#8221;3591&#8243;]
[estate_teaser id=&#8221;8&#8243;]
<h2>Recent Properties</h2>
<div  class='portfolio-itemlist-col3 group-itemlist-3 grid' >
<!-- estate-entry --><div class='object_entry object_third' id="object_3602" style="">      
        <div class='object_left'>
        <a href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/cityloft-brooklyn/'><img  src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/estate_0095.jpg' alt='Cityloft Brooklyn' /></a>       </div>
        <div class='object_right'>
            <a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/cityloft-brooklyn/" class="headline"><h3>Cityloft Brooklyn</h3></a>
             
            New York &rsaquo;           New York <div class='hr'></div><div class='second_line'>Sale &rsaquo; Suite     
                </div>
                <div class="e_entry">
                    <span class="bed">4</span>
                    <span class="bath">4</span>
                    <span class="size">236</span>
                </div> 
            <div class='hr'></div>
            <p class='object_buttons'>
            <a class='sc_button square small block_button black' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/cityloft-brooklyn/'>$ 256,000 </a>            <a class='object_read_more sc_button square small  darkgray' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/cityloft-brooklyn/'>More...</a></p>  
                
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!-- estate-entry --><div class='object_entry object_third' id="object_3601" style="">        
        <div class='object_left'>
        <a href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/penthouse-staten-island/'><img  src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/estate_0094.jpg' alt='Penthouse Staten Island' /></a>       </div>
        <div class='object_right'>
            <a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/penthouse-staten-island/" class="headline"><h3>Penthouse Staten Island</h3></a>
             
            New York &rsaquo;           New York <div class='hr'></div><div class='second_line'>Sale &rsaquo; Suite     
                </div>
                <div class="e_entry">
                    <span class="bed">3</span>
                    <span class="bath">2</span>
                    <span class="size">65</span>
                </div> 
            <div class='hr'></div>
            <p class='object_buttons'>
            <a class='sc_button square small block_button black' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/penthouse-staten-island/'>$ 117,000 </a>          <a class='object_read_more sc_button square small  darkgray' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/penthouse-staten-island/'>More...</a></p>  
                
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!-- estate-entry --><div class='object_entry object_third' id="object_3600" style="">        
        <div class='object_left'>
        <a href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/domicile-in-manhattan/'><img  src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/estate_0093.jpg' alt='Domicile in Manhattan' /></a>       </div>
```

Comment: Hi Kyle Carper. Would it be possible to also have the html code so I can run your code on my computer and try to help you

Comment: <ul id="menu" class="main-menu main-menu-1 sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow"><li id="menu-item-3899" class="c1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-1952 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children has-submenu sfHover"><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/" data-v="go Back">Home<span>go Back</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; visibility: visible;">

Comment: Hi Kyle Carper. I have tried running your code on my computer. Your css in your question was not pasted correctly or not all of it was pasted. I am looking at your html that you sent and I cant seem to see the dropdown menu or dropdown links that you want to apply styling on hover. I will highly appreciate it if you paste all the css and show me the entire navigation html (if it's not all of it). You can just click edit in your question to do so

Comment: Hi Mega, I posted the html (index) code, as much as would allow me, I can recognize that I happen to paste the portion that contains the main menu/sub menu that I'm having trouble with, again, the menu is not displaying the dropdown submenu or no activity on hover whatsoever. Did you need me to somehow paste the css too? I don't know if I will be allowed to paste that much code...css in addition to what I've already posted, I hope what I have managed to post for now is at least some help so far, thanks again for whatever you can do to assist me! Standing by. . .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking so long to respond. Thank you for giving me your entire navigation html.

HERE IS AN EXAMPLE OF HOW A BASIC ON HOVER DROPDOWN MENU WORKS LIKE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show Hide Dropdown Using CSS</title>
<style>
    ul {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown {
        min-width: 100%; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        background: #f2f2f2;
        display: none; /* Set it to display none so it can not show your content */
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
    ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
        display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown li {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products ▾</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS HOW YOU CAN DO IT USING THE CODE  YOU GAVE ME:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <style>
   // THIS IS JUST THE CSS
      ul li a:hover {
        color: red;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul.sub-menu {
        min-width: 100%; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        background: #f2f2f2;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
    ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
        display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }
    ul li ul.sub-menu li {
        display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <section id="overheader">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="fleft">
          <i class='sc_fa_icon icon-phone'></i><a href="tel: 232-122-5932">Call us now: (232) 122-5932</a>
        </div>
        <div class="fright text-right">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="page" class="page">
      <header id="headline">
        <div id="headmenu">
          <div id="nav_gradient">
            <div id="navline_wrap">
              <div id="nav" class="page">
                <div class="inner">
                  <div id="brand">
                    <a href="https://besthomes4sale.info">
                      <img src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/themes/casamia/7league/default/logo.png'
                        alt='' /> </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="navleft">
                    <nav class="menu-main-container">
                      <ul id="menu" class="main-menu main-menu-1 sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
                        <li id="menu-item-4088"
                          class="c1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-1952 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children has-submenu">
                          <a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/" data-v="go Back">Home<span>go Back</span></a>
                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-4108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><i
                                class='icon-arrow-up'></i><a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/home-search/">Home
                                Search</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/home-recent-objects/">Home Recent Objects</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/home-featured-objects/">Home Featured Objects</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/home-map/">Home Map</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4091" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/fullwidth-slider/imageheader/">Page with
                                Imageheader</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4089" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/fullwidth-slider/home-mapslider/">Mapslider</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4076"
                              class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-1952 current_page_item">
                              <a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/">Fullwidth Slider</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/home-boxed-slider/">Home boxed Slider</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4090" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/fullwidth-slider/home-with-headlines/">Home with
                                Headline</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/fullwidth-slider/elasticslider/">Smooth slider</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-4070"
                          class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-submenu">
                          <a href="#">Listings</a>
                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-4106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/homes-grid/">Listing grid</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/homes-list/">Listing list</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4071"
                              class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-submenu">
                              <a href="#">Browse by&#8230;</a>
                              <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-4072"
                                  class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-estatecity"><a
                                    href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estatecity/new-york/">City: New York</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-4073"
                                  class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-estatekind"><a
                                    href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estatekind/house/">Kind: House</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-4074"
                                  class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-estatefeature"><a
                                    href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estatefeature/pool/">Feature: Pool</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-4075"
                                  class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-estatetype"><a
                                    href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estatetype/sale/">Type: Sale</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-4069"
                          class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-submenu">
                          <a href="#">Shortcodes</a>
                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-4078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/elements/">Typographie</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/columns/">Columns &#038; Sections</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4095" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/flickr/">Flickr</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4096" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/videos/">Videos</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4098" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/testimonial-shortcodes/">Testimonial Shortcodes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4097" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/google-maps/">Google Maps</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/3096-2/">Skills</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-4077"
                          class="c1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children has-submenu">
                          <a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/"
                            data-v="Stunning!">Features<span>Stunning!</span></a>
                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-4079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/sidebar-right/">Sidebar right</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4080" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/sidebar-left/">Sidebar left</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/feature/full-width/">Full width</a></li>
                       
                            <li id="menu-item-4103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/portfolio/sortable-3-col/">Portfolio Sortable</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                                href="https://besthomes4sale.info/portfolio/quickgallery-3-col/">Quickgallery</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-3950" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a
                            href="https://besthomes4sale.info/blog/" data-v="Our Blog">News<span>Our Blog</span></a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </nav>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <!-- elastic slider -->
      <div id="smoothslider_container" class="nocsl  ">
        <div id="smoothslider">
          <section id="smooth_header" class="header custom_header smoothslider">
            <a class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/blog-1.jpg'><img
                src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/blog-1.jpg' alt='' /></a><a
              class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0010.jpg'><img
                src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0010.jpg' alt='' /></a><a
              class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0006.jpg'><img
                src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0006.jpg' alt='' /></a><a
              class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0009.jpg'><img
                src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0009.jpg' alt='' /></a><a
              class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0007.jpg'><img
                src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0007.jpg' alt='' /></a><a
              class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0008.jpg'><img
                src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/blog_0008.jpg' alt='' /></a><a
              class='prettyPhoto' href='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/blog-4.jpg'><img
                src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/blog-4.jpg' alt='' /></a>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
   
      </script>

      <div class="mainsection">
        <div class="inner">

          <!-- Page  -->
          <div id="page-sidebar-no-sidebar">
            <div id="content" class="equal_height">
              <div class='sc_column one_fourth '>
                <h4><i class='sc_fa_icon icon-compass' style='font-size: 22px; '></i> &nbsp;Responsive</h4>
                <p>Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore sed
                  diam nonumy.</p>
              </div>
              <div class='sc_column one_fourth '>
                <h4><i class='sc_fa_icon icon-font' style='font-size: 22px; '></i> &nbsp;600+ Webfonts</h4>
                <p>Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore sed
                  diam nonumy.</p>
              </div>
              <div class='sc_column one_fourth '>
                <h4><i class='sc_fa_icon icon-th-large' style='font-size: 22px; '></i> &nbsp;SEO ready</h4>
                <p>Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore sed
                  diam nonumy.</p>
              </div>
              <div class='sc_column one_fourth last '>
                <h4><i class='sc_fa_icon icon-plus' style='font-size: 22px; '></i> &nbsp;Multipurpose</h4>
                <p>Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore sed
                  diam nonumy.</p>
              </div>
              <div class='clear'></div>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p class="tagline">Our Featured Properties<span>Some really interesting properties for you</span></p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              [estate_teaser id=&#8221;3591&#8243;]
              [estate_teaser id=&#8221;8&#8243;]
              <h2>Recent Properties</h2>
              <div class='portfolio-itemlist-col3 group-itemlist-3 grid'>
                <!-- estate-entry -->
                <div class='object_entry object_third' id="object_3602" style="">
                  <div class='object_left'>
                    <a href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/cityloft-brooklyn/'><img
                        src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/estate_0095.jpg'
                        alt='Cityloft Brooklyn' /></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='object_right'>
                    <a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/cityloft-brooklyn/" class="headline">
                      <h3>Cityloft Brooklyn</h3>
                    </a>

                    New York &rsaquo; New York <div class='hr'></div>
                    <div class='second_line'>Sale &rsaquo; Suite
                    </div>
                    <div class="e_entry">
                      <span class="bed">4</span>
                      <span class="bath">4</span>
                      <span class="size">236</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='hr'></div>
                    <p class='object_buttons'>
                      <a class='sc_button square small block_button black'
                        href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/cityloft-brooklyn/'>$ 256,000 </a> <a
                        class='object_read_more sc_button square small  darkgray'
                        href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/cityloft-brooklyn/'>More...</a>
                    </p>

                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!-- estate-entry -->
                <div class='object_entry object_third' id="object_3601" style="">
                  <div class='object_left'>
                    <a href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/penthouse-staten-island/'><img
                        src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/estate_0094.jpg'
                        alt='Penthouse Staten Island' /></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='object_right'>
                    <a href="https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/penthouse-staten-island/" class="headline">
                      <h3>Penthouse Staten Island</h3>
                    </a>

                    New York &rsaquo; New York <div class='hr'></div>
                    <div class='second_line'>Sale &rsaquo; Suite
                    </div>
                    <div class="e_entry">
                      <span class="bed">3</span>
                      <span class="bath">2</span>
                      <span class="size">65</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='hr'></div>
                    <p class='object_buttons'>
                      <a class='sc_button square small block_button black'
                        href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/penthouse-staten-island/'>$ 117,000 </a> <a
                        class='object_read_more sc_button square small  darkgray'
                        href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/penthouse-staten-island/'>More...</a>
                    </p>

                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!-- estate-entry -->
                <div class='object_entry object_third' id="object_3600" style="">
                  <div class='object_left'>
                    <a href='https://besthomes4sale.info/estate/domicile-in-manhattan/'><img
                        src='https://besthomes4sale.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/estate_0093.jpg'
                        alt='Domicile in Manhattan' /></a>
                  </div>

                  css
</body>

</html>
```

Of course the styling is not very nice(becuase I dont have your entire css) but hope this works for you

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna enter everything in tonight. Mega, thank you so much for your time and attention! I will update you and let you know how things are turning out later. Thanks again!

Comment: Mega, YOU ARE MY HERO! Worked like a charm! Thank you infinitely for you time and dedication to my unbelievably annoying issue! Now my non-issue, thanks again!

Comment: It was my pleasure helping you. Thank you